# fgets returns null on non empty file

Tags: c, file-io, null, fgets

I am trying to read from a file a non specific number of integers in pairs. I also want to skip lines that start with #. My problem is that nothing gets printed. When I tried to printf the value returned by fgets, it printed null. I would really appreciate a little help since I am not very experienced with C and I would be very grateful if you did not focus on feof since I have already read why is feof bad.

The file looks like this:

```
#This must
#be
#skipped
1233 14432
4943928  944949
11233   345432
```

And the code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct{
int start;
int end;
}path;
int main()
{
    path* array;
    array=malloc(5*sizeof(path));
    if(array==NULL){
    printf("Error allocating memory\n");
    abort();
    }


    FILE* fd=fopen("File.txt","r");
    if(fd==NULL){
    printf("Error opening file\n");
    abort();
    }
    char buff[200];
    int counter=0;
    if(fopen==NULL){
       printf("Error opening file\n");
        abort();
    }
    char c;
    while(!feof(fd)||counter==6){
        fgets(buff,200,fd);
        c=buff[0];
        if(strcmp(buff[0],"#")){
            continue;
        }
        sscanf(&buff,"%d %d",array[counter].start,array[counter].end);
        printf("%d\t%d\n",array[counter].start,array[counter].end);
        counter++;
    }


    fclose(fd);
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This statement  if(fopen==NULL){ or this one if(strcmp(buff[0],"#")){ does not make sense.

Comment: `counter == 6` should be `counter < 5`

Comment: Yeah, don't `strcmp` to compare two individual `char`s.  You can compare them with `==`

Comment: And you should combine the conditions with `&&`, not `||`.

Comment: [Why `while(!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Comment: Where do you check the value of `fgets()`?

Comment: Exactly. You claim "fgets() is returning null", but you never look at the return value of fgets, so how would you know? It could be returning anything.

Comment: "fgets returns null on non empty file" is not demonstrated by this code - return value never checked.

Comment: Azzarian, Save time, enable all compiler warnings.

Comment: Azzarian "I would be very grateful if you did not focus on feof since I have already read why is feof bad" which counter-productive  as `while(!feof(fd) ...` is a _significant_ part of the problem.  Consider fixing that and review compiler warnings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, answering the title of your question: `fgets()` returns `NULL` at end of file and not when a file is empty.

Anyway, your test in the `while` loop is incorrect:

- `feof()` only gives a true result when you have **already tried read and you have already hit the end of file with an unsuccessful read**.  As `read` tries to give you as many bytes as it can... or none at all if end of file, the only way to get end of file condition is **after you failed to read something**. It is far better to check for `fgets()` result, as it returns `NULL` on being unable to read anything now. (and not in the last read) so

  ```
  while(fgets(buff, sizeof buff, fd) != NULL)
  ```

  or just

  ```
  while(fgets(buff, sizeof buff, fd))
  ```

  would be far better.  Also, see how I use the `sizeof` operator to use the size of the used buffer, instead of repeating (and being error prone) the actual number of bytes at two places.  If you decide to change the size of the buffer, you'll need also to change the actual number of bytes to read in the `fgets()` call, making the possibility of forgetting one of them an opportunity to run into trouble.
- you order to stay in the loop only while **`!feof()` OR when `counter == 6`**  (first, this will make the control to enter the loop when counter is equal to 6, *despite you have reached EOF or not*, this cannot be correct) Think that you **only get out of the loop when both conditions are false** (this means `feof()` returns true **and also** `counter != 6`), you had better to write:

  ```
  while(fgets(buff, sizeof buff, fd) && counter < max_number_of_iterations)
  ```
- The test

  ```
  if(strcmp(buff[0],"#"))
  ```

  is also incorrect, as `buff[0]` is a character (indeed, it is the first character read in the buffer, and `"#"` is a string literal (not a character)  Probably you got at least a warning from the compiler, from which you say no word.  You had better to test both characters for equality, as in

  ```
  if (buff[0] == '#')  /* this time '#' is a character literal, not a string literal */
  ```
- in the line

  ```
  if (fopen == NULL)
  ```

  `fopen` by itself is a pointer to the library function `fopen(3)` which is not what you want (`fopen` is **always** `!= NULL`) but

  ```
  if (fd == NULL){
  ```

  (which you do before, so you had better to eliminate al this code)
- you define a `char c;`, then initialize it to the first char of `buff`, and then you don't use it at all.  This has no impact in your code but it's bad style and confounds maintainers in the future.
- in the line `sscanf(&buff, "%d %d", ....`  you don't need to pass `&buff`, while `buff` is *already a char pointer*.  It is better to pass it `buff`.n  But instead, you **need to pass pointers to the variables you are reading** so you need it corrected into:

  ```
  sscanf(buff, "%d%d", &array[counter].start, &array[counter].end);
  ```

  not doing so will make an **Undefined Behaviour** that will be difficult to pursue, as the use of uninitialised variables (and more on, pointers to variables) will make the code probably work at first, but fail when it has got to production for a while... this is a **very serious error**.

Your code, with all these errors corrected, should look like:

## pru.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define N (5)  /* I have  defined this constant so you can 
                * change its value without having to go all 
                * the code for occurrences of it and 
                * changing those */

typedef struct{
    int start;
    int end;
} path;

int main()
{
    path* array = malloc(N*sizeof(path)); /* better declare and init */
    if(array==NULL){
        printf("Error allocating memory\n");
        abort();  /* have you tried exit(EXIT_FAILURE); ?? */
    }

    FILE* fd=fopen("File.txt","r");
    if(fd==NULL){
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        abort();
    }
    char buff[200];
    int counter=0;
    while(fgets(buff, sizeof buff, fd) && counter < N){
        if(buff[0] == '#'){
            continue;
        }
        sscanf(buff, "%d %d", &array[counter].start, &array[counter].end);
        printf("%d\t%d\n", array[counter].start, array[counter].end);
        counter++;
    }

    fclose(fd);
    free(array);

    return 0;
}
```

Running the code shows:

```
$ pru
1233    14432
4943928 944949
11233   345432
```

with the `File.txt` you posted.

## Finally, a hint:

Despite of your interest in knowing **only** the reasons of your loop falling, and not why `feof()` is of no use here (and many other things you just don't ask for and that are wrong in your code), if that is actually the case, you had better to post an example **that only shows the failing behaviour** as recommended by the page [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you should have read and which I recommend you to do.

Answer (score 1):

You should not check `feof()` in the `while` condition. See [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong).

The loop should be:

```
while (fcounter < 5 && fgets(buff, 200, fd))
```